# python decorated dataclass method is shared for all instances

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators, python-dataclasses

I'm implementing a python decorator with an internal memory (represented by `counter` below).

It seams the decorator variables are shared across instances of a `dataclass` while being different for instances of a common `class`.

Why is so? And is there a cleaner/easier solution other than checking if `f` belongs to a class or not and if so, if the class is a `dataclass`?

```
import dataclasses

def decorator(f):
    counter = {}
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        key = repr([f.__name__, args, kwargs])
        counter[key] = counter.setdefault(key, 0)+1
        result = f(*args, **kwargs)
        print(f"{counter[key]}", end=" ")
        return result
    return wrapper

@dataclasses.dataclass
class D:
    @decorator
    def foo(self):
        pass

class C:
    @decorator
    def foo(self):
        pass
```

Despide `C` and `D` being very similar, the code below shows that the instances of normal `object` have different `counter` each:

```
>>> for i in range(5):
...     c = C()
...     c.foo()
1 1 1 1 1
```

While when using the `dataclass` instead, the `counter` is shared:

```
>>> for i in range(5):
...     c = D()
...     c.foo()
1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decorator syntax is a shortcut for function application, so each use of `@decorator` is a separate call to `decorator`, each of which creates a new `dict` associated with the decorated function.

So it's one counter per decorated function, and there is one decorated function per class in your example.

But then there's another problem.
Your key depends on each class's `__repr__` function, as `*args` includes the object itself.

For `C`, `__repr__` is not defined, so `object.__repr__` is used, producing a unique key for each instance.

For `D`, `D.__repr__` returns a generic string `'D()'` for every instance, so you aren't getting unique keys for instances of `D`.

The solution is to be more explicit in constructing the key. Perhaps something like

```
from collections import Counter


def decorator(f):
    counter = Counter()
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        key = repr([id(f.__name__), [id(x) for x in args], [id(x) for x in kwargs.items()]])
        counter[key] += 1
        result = f(*args, **kwargs)
        # print(f"{counter[key]}", end=" ")
        return result
    return wrapper
```

Comment: Thank you ! But actually, your previous answer is necessary… indeed, the counter is just always shared... it's the key that is different between `C` and `D`. I suggest you complement your answer with what you wrote before.

Comment: Ah, I thought I just misinterpreted your original question.

Comment: Alone it was not explaining the problem, but I think it's part of the whole explanation....

Comment: Just folded the deleted answer into the beginning of this one.

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to have a unique counter per place where it is used?

Comment: The counter is unique to each method you decorate, not each class. It just "looks" like there's one counter per class because each of your classes only has one method.

Answer (score 0):

As you're decorating methods rather than functions, the value of `*args` in `wrapper(*args, **kwargs)` will be a one element tuple containing the implicit `self`.

Your `key` value would then look like this `['foo', (<__main__.C object at 0x7fe8945403c8>,), {}]`.

As those instances of `C` and `D` get garbage collected, sometimes Python will reuse the same memory address and sometimes not, leading to different keys.

I'm not sure why Python would reuse dataclass addresses more than for regular classes.

If you change `wrapper` to expect `self`, you should get consistent results.

```py
def decorator(f):
    counter = {}
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        key = repr([f.__name__, args, kwargs])
        counter[key] = counter.setdefault(key, 0)+1
        result = f(self, *args, **kwargs)
        print(f"{counter[key]}", end=" ")
        return result
    return wrapper
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it matches with my investigation. However, my decorator is supposed to be used on functions, properties or methods transparantly... The original implementation features a class instead of `wrapper`, but the behaviour is the same...

Comment: It's not reusing anything; `D.__repr__` simply doesn't use the id in its output. `repr(d)  == 'D()'` for every instance of `D`.